# Adding more IP Addresses to a Subnet in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, cidr, ips

I have a Subnet with CIDR 10.0.4.0/28 (15 IP addresses), which is now exhausted; so I want to add more IP addresses.

Is it possible to add more IP addresses to the subnet? I see that I can add a second CIDR range to the VPC.

If not, what are the best options, perhaps one of these?:

1. Create a 2nd subnet (would require more administration and a 2nd Security Gateway, etc.)
2. Create a 2nd (larger) subnet and migrate everything from the first subnet to this one
3. Other?

Comment: I don't think you can enlarge a subnet, you'll have to delete it and create a new one, or just create an additional subnet. Subnets provide no real isolation unless you set it up, so just create another one in the same AZ. If you want to move EC2 instances I think you will have to take snapshots / AMIs of your EC2 instances and recreate them in the new subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implement IPv6 and no longer care about the size of private prefixes.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/ipv6-on-aws/planning-ipv6-adoption-in-the-aws-cloud-network.html)

Although getting the real benefits of IPv6 only subnets will require some design. [NAT64](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-nat64-dns64.html) for talking to v4, updated security rules, dual stack for certain subnets.